# Cant connect socket with Node Js and React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, websocket

Im trying to make a chat application with node js and react , but on msg-receive its not happening anything , i tried to figured it out but nothing is working .
So Now i think that the socket its working fine until the part of msg-receive ,
On the Node i think everything is working fine , but the problem is on the react part.

**NODE JS CODE :**

```
const io = socket(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        credentials: true,
    },
});

global.onlineUsers = new Map();
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    global.chatSocket = socket;
    socket.on("add-user", (userId) => {
        onlineUsers.set(userId, socket.id);

    });

    socket.on("send-msg", (data) => {
        const sendUserSocket = onlineUsers.get(data.to);
        console.log(sendUserSocket);
        if (sendUserSocket) {
           socket.to(sendUserSocket).emit("msg-recieve", data.message);
         
}
    });
});
```

**REACT CODE**

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
 const [msgs, setMsgs] = useState([]);
 const [arrivalMessage, setArrivalMessage] = useState();
 const socket = useRef();
  const host = "http://localhost:3001";
useEffect(() => {
    if (currentChat.length > 0) {
      async function ChatMsg() {
        const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/receiveMessages", {
          from: currentUser.id,
          to: currentChat[0].id
        });
        setMsgs(response.data);

        socket.current = io(host);
        socket.current.emit("add-user", currentUser.id);
      }
      ChatMsg();
    }

  }, [currentChat]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (socket.current) {
  
      socket.current.on("msg-recieve", (msg) => {
        setArrivalMessage({ fromSelf: false, message: msg });
      });
    }
  }, []);
 useEffect(() => {
    arrivalMessage && setMsgs((prev) => [...prev, arrivalMessage]);
  }, [arrivalMessage]);
```

Comment: Where are you emitting the event `send-msg`?

Comment: Did not past it

Comment: Note that you are emitting the event `msg-recieve` only within the `send-msg` event, so  at first you should emit a `send-msg` event in order to send the `msg-recieve` as well.